# Element библиотека. Проблема с передачей данных в generateDate у el-transfer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ui

Формирование данных у блока el-transfer происходит нативно до выполнения всего остального кода в блоке generateData. 
Мне необходимо сделать axios заспрос к серверу, а полученные данные передать в date, для отображения в el-transfer.

Есть ли у кого-то пример похожего работающего кода или какая-то информация по этому вопросу? Никак не могу решить проблему, пока что, уже использовал промисы.

Comment: Что за el-transfer? Что за generateData? Так-то не экстрасенсы тут в большинстве своём. Минимальный код с примером покажите. Только не весь проект.

Comment: оберните el-transfer в другой компонент, в этом компоненте сделайте необходимый запрос, после получения ответа отобразите el-transfer